# Use external gem in logstash plugin

Tags: logstash

I was trying to create filter plugin for logstash.
I wasnt' able to add external gem to plugin.

How to add external gem to logstash plugin, any pointer will be helpful !

Comment: if the answer fulfills your question, please accept it.

Comment: @tedder42 I didn't tried his solution, I used a java library instead. I don't know if that solution works or not.   So I left it on basis of upvotes

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /opt/logstash
env GEM_HOME=vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9 GEM_PATH="" java -jar vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar -S gem install gemname
```

If you're installing a local gem file, put the path to the file in GEM_PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've done that using a jar file. 
I found that easy. 
Thanks for answer . !

Comment: @SumitMurari can you specify about your approach. How can i go about doing the same ?

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this:

Today I needed to install the `thrift` and `finagle-thrift` gems. I did:

`java -jar /opt/logstash/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar -I/opt/logstash/lib -S gem install -i /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9 --no-ri --no-rdoc thrift finagle-thrift`

Worked perfectly.